# remove html tags in between two symbols

Tags: php, regex

I would like to remove html tags in between two $ signs, example:

```
<p>this is $ and <em> example of </em> what $ I need help with</p>
```

I'd like to remove the <em> tags in between $, I came up with the following expression but its not quite there

```
re = <[^>]*>(?=.*\$)
```

I tried using look behind to finish the job but couldn't figure it out

Comment: I recommend reading http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1344955

Comment: I like it, but I'm not sure how else to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = '<p>this is $ and <em> example of </em> what $ I need help $with</p>';
echo preg_replace_callback(
    '~\$.*?\$~',
    function($matches) {
        return strip_tags($matches[0]);
    },
    $str);
```